# Create and update CSS in two methods

Tags: javascript, css, dom, methods, updates

How to update universe variable css using create and update methods below:

```
var gravity = {
    universe: function (width, height, color) {
        this._width = width;
        this._height = height;
        this._color = color;

        var universe;

        var create = function () {
            universe = document.createElement("div");
            universe.style.border = "5px solid #DDD";
            universe.style.overflow = "hidden";
            document.body.appendChild(universe);
        };
        var update = function () {
            universe.style.width = this._width + "px";
            universe.style.height = this._height + "px";
            universe.style.backgroundColor = this._color;
        };

        create();
        update();
    }
}
```

Update method doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a useless report. Is there an error? Does the wrong thing happen?... Also, what is `this._width` and others, since your code snippet does not show them defined?

Comment: I rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

your update method "doesnt work" because when you call it, `this` references the window object. 
if you wanted it to work, one possible solution would be to set `var that = this;` outside of the update method and replace all references to `this` with `that` inside the method.

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) should clear things up a bit